# word spacing and negative margins in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, text-align, margin, word-spacing

I have three columns with percentage widths and i am using word spacing, padding and negative margins in order to put the columns with a gutter in between. When i use the text-align property with values right and center chrome and firefox render the position of the columns very different.

the code is as follows:

```
body {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 500px;
  word-spacing: 36px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: -24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}

.item-1{
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 40%;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
}
```

with the following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">A</div>
  <div class="item-2">B</div>
  <div class="item-3">C</div>
</div>
```

You can see a [fiddle live version here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pitxon/3zJZe/1/)In the example with text align set to right firefox do what i expect but chrome puts part of the columns out of their container box, is there any way to fix this? or is just and edge case without solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `word-spacing` to control layout?  As opposed to margins?

Comment: yes because i can use percentages for the width of the items.

Comment: That's what's causing the issue in Chrome, and it's not what it's intended for.  Can't you do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3zJZe/2/

Comment: yeap this works for this case, but it will not work if all three columns are set with a width of 33.333%. Is this the standar behavior in chrome?, no exists any hack to fix it?

Comment: I don't know if it's standard behaviour, but word spacing shouldn't be used for layout.  You can achieve that by adding some additional HTML and then use padding (because box-sizing includes padding in it's width). http://jsfiddle.net/3zJZe/3/

Comment: yeah i know the "gutter padding" thing but the i need to use background-clip to fit the background properly, i cant use borders also. I know also that word-spacing shouldnt be used to layout but css world is like this :)

Comment: Why do you need background clip?  The fiddle I gave doesn't use it.

Comment: if i use padding as gutters and i want to put a background just fot the content i have to clip the background or to have another box inside with the background as normal

Comment: Yeah, another box inside (like my `.inner`).  Is that an issue?

Comment: well, it is or not, the thing is the different behavior in chrome and firefox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49616/discussion-between-davidpauljunior-and-twissell)